# Weird "Designer1.cs" files created

Tags: visual-studio-2008, designer

How does visual studio link files to their corresponding designer.cs files?  I have a strange situation that's occurred with both the DataSet designer and also the L2S DBML designer where it's ignoring the DataSet.Designer.cs and has created and used a DataSet.Designer1.cs instead.  How can I switch it back?

Comment: Wow, just read that back - that's a whole lotta "designer" :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Thanks to Zendar's suggestion, this is what I did:

1. Close Visual Studio.
2. Use TortoiseSVN to rename the `DataContext1.designer.cs` file to `DataContext.designer.cs`, so the rename is picked up by source control.
3. Opened `MyProject.csproj` in Textpad.
4. Performed search and replace for `DataContext1.designer` with `DataContext.designer` (found 2 instances).
5. Save and close.

Re-opening and building the solution in Visual Studio confirmed this worked.  Thanks Zendar!

Comment: This solution solved same problem with ".resx" files on vs2013.

Comment: Great that fixes the problem. I found that also myself. But how can you prevent these stupid *1.Designer.cs files being generated in the first place? Happens each time when editing a resx file in VS2015.2 for me.

Answer (score 8):

Information about related files is written in project files (*.csproj). This may fix problem:

1. exclude DataSet designer from project
2. close Visual studio
3. remove Designer1.cs from disk
4. remove Designer.cs from disk (if it exists)
5. start Visual studio
6. open DataSet designer
7. now you should have Designer.cs

Alternative would be to try to change information in *.csproj file and then to rename Designer1 to Designer in all places it occurs. I did not try this, but it may work.

Comment: +1 you are a gentleman and a scholar, I thank you. :)  I actually did the renaming thing you suggested and it worked a treat.  Marvellous.

Comment: Changed the occurrences in the *.csproj file and it did the trick, thanks

Answer (score 0):

`<LastGenOutput>` was set improperly in the .csproj file. Once that was updated, the extra file stopped being generated for me.