# New Designer1.cs created every time I try to add queries to my DataSet.xsd (VS2013)

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2013, xsd

I'm working on an application on VS2013 and have this bug right now which is every time I add an SQL query I have a new Designer.cs file created, which is called Designer1.cs. Then of course impossible to run the app cause there are conflicts between the 2 files.

Does anyone know why it's doing this and how to fix it? I can't work on my application anymore because of that.

I've read some posts about it, done the trick but still got some new Designer1.cs file being created after that.

[Weird “Designer1.cs” files created](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2551594/weird-designer1-cs-files-created)

[Dataset Designer.cs generate Designer1.cs after taking update from SVN in VS2013](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30129519/dataset-designer-cs-generate-designer1-cs-after-taking-update-from-svn-in-vs2013)

I suspect something is wrong with my project settings but really don't know how to fix it. Is it possible to copy all the content of the application to a new project easily? I'm using VS2013 for school and don't know much about it, some help would be really appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I have had the same in three projects. Sometimes deleting the .sln-file helps, sometimes it is neccessary to copy all files to a new created project, excluding the sln-file.
I don't know why this bug comes up, I looked for help but nothing to find. I wrote to Microsofts develloper forum - no answer.
The description in your first link - the answer of zendar - is very good for the first time. The excluding is not nessecary, but deleting .designer1.cs after renaming in the explorer is reqired.